# Failed in process with error Internal : Failed to perform step 1 in Write Stage 'input' on page 'Input' - Not Connected

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I created object to launch, and another action to input username and password. Tested launch page successful, then I click the input action --> set next stage --> click go. Successful too.

When i apply in process it failed.

Error: Internal : Failed to perform step 1 in Write Stage 'input' on page 'Input' - Not Connected

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: You posted this same exact inquiry yesterday: [Internal : Failed to perform step 1 in Write Stage '' on page '' - Not Connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270029/internal-failed-to-perform-step-1-in-write-stage-on-page-not-connected)

Comment: It failed in process but successful in object by action using set next stage. Any idea?

Comment: It's not connected - try a

Answer (score 0):

**Internal : Failed to perform step 1 in Write Stage 'input' on-page 'Input' - Not Connected**

This error will come when your appliaction is not attached to the application Modeler. As you are performing the navigation after Launching the application then it should not happen. this happened generally when your application takes time to launch.

For resolution: You can add explicitly Attach for application with providing window text, process name and child index. then do your actions.